# Radar chart mi and max axis values

Tags: amcharts

How to limit my Radar chart from 0 to 10?

I have tried to set `minimum` and `maximum` keys, but this did not work.

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

    const chart = am4core.createFromConfig({
      'xAxes': [{
        'type': 'CategoryAxis',
        'minimum': 0,
        'maximum': 10,
        'dataFields': {
          'category': 'category'
        },
        'tooltip': {
          'disabled': true
        },
        'renderer': {
          'labels': {
            'fill': '#757575',
            'fontSize': 12
          }
        }
      }],
      'yAxes': [{
        'type': 'ValueAxis',
        'minimum': 0,
        'maximum': 10,
        'tooltip': {
          'disabled': true
        },
        'renderer': {
          'labels': {
            'fill': '#757575',
            'fontSize': 12
          }
        }
      }],
      'legend': {
        'position': 'bottom',
        'fontSize': '1rem',
        'fontWeight': '400'
      },
      'cursor': {},
      'series': [
        {
          'type': 'RadarSeries',
          'dataFields': {
            'valueY': 'value1',
            'categoryX': 'category'
          },
          'fill': '#4a90e2',
          'stroke': '#4a90e2',
          'strokeWidth': 3,
          'tooltipText': '{valueY}',
          'renderer': {
            'tooltip': {
              'fill': '#fff'
            }
          },
          'tooltip': {
            'getFillFromObject': false,
            'background': {
              'fill': '#4a90e2'
            }
          },
          'name': 'Средняя оценка',
          'bullets': [{
            'type': 'CircleBullet'
          }]
        }],

      'data': data.map(el => {

        return {
          'category': el.sLabel,
          'value1': el.iRating
        };
      })
    }, 'radar-chart', am4charts.RadarChart);
```

I expect my chart axis to always start at 0 and end at 10.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle? Or at least post what your data looks like? As far as your question goes, have you taken a look at this documentation: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/value-axis/#Adjusting_scale?

Comment: @DavidLiang Thank you! It was all about setting 'strictMinMax': true property in my case.